# Why my theme is not applied in my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, colors, themes

**Problem Explanation - Color Theme Issue:**

In my Flutter app, I encountered an issue related to the color theme. I had defined a custom color theme using the **`ThemeData`** class and tried to use the **`primaryColor`** property to set the background color of an **`ElevatedButton`**. However, the background color of the button was not changing as expected.

**Expected Behavior:** I expected the **`ElevatedButton`** background color to change according to the **`primaryColor`** defined in my custom theme. The **`primaryColor`** was set to a specific hex color value, and I wanted the button to have that color as its background.

**Actual Behavior:** Despite correctly setting up the custom theme and referencing **`Theme.of(context).primaryColor`** for the button's background color, the button was not taking on the color I had defined. It appeared to retain its default background color.

**Code Context:** Here's a simplified version of the relevant parts of my code:

utils.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension ColorExtension on String {
  toColor() {
    var hexString = this;
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: Login());
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Define el tema personalizado
    final Color primaryColor = "#331b1b".toColor();
    final Color secondaryColor = "#c36317".toColor();

    final ThemeData myTheme = ThemeData(
      primaryColor: primaryColor,
      hintColor: Colors.green,
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: myTheme,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const Home(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                       backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,),
                  child: const Text('Ir a Home')),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are nesting one MaterialApp inside another. If you remove the inner MaterialApp and set the theme in the outer MaterialApp, everything works as expected:

```
final Color primaryColor = "#331b1b".toColor();
final Color secondaryColor = "#c36317".toColor();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  // Define el tema personalizado
  final ThemeData myTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: primaryColor,
    hintColor: Colors.green,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(theme: myTheme, home: const Login());
  }
}

extension ColorExtension on String {
  toColor() {
    var hexString = this;
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const Home(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
                child: const Text('Ir a Home')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```